# Thymeleaf th tag in blc tag

Tags: thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

my problem is following:
in this code

```
    <header>
        <h1 th:utext="${BLC_PAGE.pageFields[menu_name]}"></h1>
    </header>

    <blc:menu resultVar="menuItems" menuName="${BLC_PAGE.pageFields[menu_name]}" />
    <ul th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(menuItems)}">
        <li th:each="menuItem : ${menuItems}">

            <a th:href="@{${menuItem.url}}" th:class="${menuItemStat.first}? 'home'">
                <span th:utext="${menuItem.label}"></span>
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
```

the line `<h1 th:utext="${BLC_PAGE.pageFields[menu_name]}"></h1>` gets the name of actual menu. I need the menuName in this line `<blc:menu resultVar="menuItems" menuName="${BLC_PAGE.pageFields[menu_name]}" />` to do the same thing, but `"${BLC_PAGE.pageFields[menu_name]}"` is not appropriate, as it is from thymeleaf tags library. Any idea how to get this this value in blc:menu tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve the Thymeleaf expression `${BLC_PAGE.pageFields[menu_name]}`, you will need to wrap it like so: `th:attr="menuName=${BLC_PAGE.pageFields[menu_name]}"`. Because menuName is not a standard HTML attribute, you won't be able to simply add the Thymeleaf namespace to menuName (i.e., `th:menuName`), and, without the `th:` namespace, Thymeleaf doesn't know that it needs to resolve any expressions. The Thymeleaf `attr` attribute allows you to use non-standard HTML attributes with Thymeleaf. For more information on setting attribute values using Thymeleaf you can review [their documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-attribute-values).

Here are links to the Broadleaf and Thymeleaf documentation on Processors and Dialects:

- Thymeleaf: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/extendingthymeleaf.html#dialects-and-processors

Comment: - Broadleaf: http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/presentation-layer#thymeleaf